# Preventing iOS input focus from jumping the page to the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

Having a little annoying bug in iOS

For example (on iphone - native) https://www.ambientlounge.eu/collections/butterfly-sofa-1/products/butterfly-wildberry-deluxe?variant=26941312775

If you click on the quantity box at the bottom you will see the page jump to the top... is there anyway to hold the page position so stop this from happening?

I tried something with setting position but did not work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var yPos = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scollTop;

  $('.sticky-product-qty input').bind('blur', function(){ 
    $("html, body").removeClass('stickyFix');
    //setTimeout(function() {
      window.scrollTo(0, yPos);
    //},0);
    console.log(yPos);
  });

  $('.sticky-product-qty input').bind('focus', function(){ 
    $("html, body").addClass('stickyFix');
    window.scrollTo(0, yPos);
  });
});
```